# Singleton confusion in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Consider this code:

```
+(id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

If I follow this singleton design pattern I can make the following assumptions:

- The allocation and initialization will only be executed once thanks
  to GCD.
- The sharedInstance class variable can only be accessed from
  within this implementation and shared among the class regardless of the instance.

First time I create the instance I would do something like:

```
MyClass *something = [MyClass sharedInstance];
```

my question is, If I call the previews code again but like this:

```
MyClass *somethingOther = [MyClass sharedInstance];
```

I can only think of one outcome.

**Outcome:**

```
static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
```

Makes sharedInstance class variable point to nil and a nil is returned so somethingOther will be nil.

But I thought that what was supposed to happen in a singleton is that  the shared instance would be returned instead.

Now consider this code:

```
+ (MotionManagerSingleton*)sharedInstance {

    static MotionManagerSingleton *_sharedInstance;
    if(!_sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
            _sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
            });
    }

    return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    

    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}
```

Here the

```
static MotionManagerSingleton *_sharedInstance;
```

Doesnt set my variable to nil, but i thought that all object pointers are initialized to nil by default.

My question is, how are these class methods returning the "sharedInstance"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One.** Non-initialized pointers are non-initialized.

```
static MotionManagerSingleton *_sharedInstance;
```

won't make your MotionManagerSingleton point to `nil`. It will point to an undefined (garbage) location.

**Two.** Variables declared `static` are initialized only once (yes, the syntax is a bit inconsistent with the semantics), so your first implementation won't null out the returned shared instance. That's a perfectly fine implementation.

Comment: so this static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil; executed for the second time will simply be ignored? therefore the previously initialized variable will be returned?

Comment: static variables are zero initialized, and with ARC all object pointers are zero initialed.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg ooo i didnt know that, Static variables are so confusing for me.

Comment: @LuisOscar, the word "static" refers to the lifetime of the variable. Its storage is static – it isn't transient like something on the stack or dynamic like something on the heap. It's permanent. Initialization only happens when that storage is initialized. Since the storage is permanent, initialization only happens once. (In actuality, the initialization is happening at compile time. The compiler bakes the storage and its initial value into the executable and it's loaded into memory when the program is loaded.)

Comment: @KenThomases be careful saying static is done at compile time. That may be true for C and Obj-C, but not for C++ or some other languages. The `static` keyword is annoyingly overloaded and has many different meanings across different platforms.

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg who talked about C++? Apart from Objective-C no other language was even mentioned in this post. And regarding Objective-C, KenThomases' answer is perfectly true.

Comment: @H2CO3 just a minor point of pedantry. I see people get confused with `static` as a keyword often, so I figure any clarification is useful